# Can I prefill the Facebook Comment Box?

Tags: facebook, dialog, comments

I would like to include the Facebook Comment Box into my website and would like to prefill the text that is displayed in the box. So I would like to change the standard text 'Add a comment....' into a text defined by myself. Is there a solution for this?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No prefilling Posts or Comments is Against Facebook TOS.

Comment: is there any way around this with the graph API?